# Python package installation

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

I am trying to install `nibabel` through `pip`:

```
pip install nibabel
```

It installs successfully, however, when I write the following code:

```
import nibabel as nib
```

I get this error :

> ```
> ImportError: No module named 'nibabel'
> ```

And when I check in the terminal using:

```
pip show nibabel
```

It shows that it exists

```
Author-email: neuroimaging@python.org

License: MIT license

Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages

Requires: numpy, six
```

This issue happens in both Python 3.x and 2.x.

Comment: Hopefully you ment `pip install nibabel` in your first Code block?!

Comment: What's the exact error message you get?

Comment: Need exact error message to help you with this. I did what you show, `pip install nibabel`, then popped an IPython shell and `import nibabel as nib` and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @Baduker Its "ImportError: No module named 'nibabel'" I edited the post sorry

Comment: Are you sure that you are using the same version to import `nibabel` as you used to install  `nibabel`

Comment: @jath03 Yes I doubled checked

Comment: And what system are you on?

Comment: How are you running Python? Clearly the one you run is not the same one `pip` found.

Comment: `pip show` does not install anything. Is the first comment correct?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can do:

If you're using `Python 2.7`, you might need `root` permission to install the `nibabel` module.

Try this:

```
pip install nibabel --user
```

Hopefully, you should get this `Successfully installed nibabel-2.2.1` message.

Then, run your `Python 2.7` environment and:

```
import nibabel as nib
```

If this doesn't help, you might want to try `virtualenv`.

Finally, double check if you meet the `nibabel` requirements e.g. `Python 2.7, or >= 3.4`.